# React Native: Network error when using axios on local server

Tags: react-native, axios, native

I'm new to react-native, I want to fetch some data from my local laravel server, but I fire the mobx action I get the following errors:

```
Network Error

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
```

This is my mobx action (I'm using flow, similar to async/await), I get 'fire' log but after that I get the error above:

```
listProducts = flow( function*(payload)
    {
        console.log('fire');
        try 
        {
            let response = yield axios.get('http://192.168.1.39:8000/api/products', { params: payload });
            
            this.posts = response.data;
            this.pagination = response.data.pagination;
            console.log(response);
            //return response;
        } 
        catch (error)
        {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
    });
```

As you can see I'm using my local IP instead of localhost, I'm also testing my app on my android device using EXPO connected to the same network as my dev laptop.

Comment: Are you using a device on the same network (i.e. where 192.168.1.39 actually refers to your localhost)?

Comment: Both my device and my computer are connected to the same network, I used ipconfig to get my IP

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I can't see errors on your code. Try to follow [this](https://medium.com/@brandoncc/how-to-handle-unhandledrejection-errors-using-axios-da82b54c6356) guide to handle `Unhandled promise rejection`. Could help you to find a clue.
In brief the guide suggest to use axios interceptors:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {}
)
```